# Minha função não esta preenchendo o valor para retornar na função

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

Estou desenvolvendo uma API de testes utilizando o nodejs e o firebird e depois de muita luta consegui fazer a consulta ao banco funcionar. Porem não estou conseguindo fazer a função retornar os valores que foram localizados na consulta. Quando exibo por meio do console.log() consigo visualizar os resultados.

```html
const client = require('../database/index');

var options = require('../database/config');

var resultado;

function setResultado(pResultado) {
    resultado = pResultado;
}

function getResultado() {
    return resultado;
}

const rows = async () => {
  try{
      
    try{
        var pool = client.pool(5, options);

        pool.get(function(err, db) {

            try{
                db.query("SELECT * FROM UCTABUSERS where UCIDUSER = 1", function(err, result) {
                setResultado(result);
                db.detach();
                });
            }catch{
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }
        });

        pool.destroy();
        
        return getResultado();

    }catch{
        return 'Não foi possivel abrir a conexão';
    }
    }catch{
        return "Não foi possivel conectar ao banco de dados";
    }
};

const User = rows();

module.exports = User;
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para resolver meu problema? Agradeço desde já! (P.S: Sou iniciante em javascript, não conheço muita coisa ainda)

Ai esta o codigo onde chamo a rota. Mas eu até testei a rota, quando coloco uma string qualquer funciona. O problema é que quando estou usando o return getResultado(); ja no final do try, o getResultado() está retornando indefinido, é como se dentro da função pool ele existisse e estive preenchido e fora não estivesse.

```html
router.get('/register', async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const user = await Users;
        return res.send({user});
    }catch{
        res.status(400).send({error : 'Falha ao registrar'})
    }
});
```

Comment: Se no console.log ele imprime os resultados talvez o problema seja no route, poderia colocar o código onde você usa o rout.get para pegar retornar a consulta?

Comment: Fiz alguns outros testes e modificações aqui e percebi que o problema acontece quando vou retornar o valor da resposta da consulta. Quando chega na linha return getResultado(); o valor do resultado esta indefinido.

Comment: coloca um `console.log(result);` logo após `setResultado(result);` e um `console.log(getResultado());` antes de `return getResultado();` para vermos se ele retorna alguma coisa no result e se realmente esta ficando salvo em setResultado. Mas de qualquer modo, você também poderia substituir o `setResultado(result);` por `return result;` assim não precisaria utilizar uma variável a mais para armazenar e um get/set. Poste o resultado por gentileza.

Comment: Boa tarde Murilo. Já fiz esse teste, o problema é que por algum motivo a função esta chamando o get antes do set(acredito que a operação que preenche o set esta demorando muito), dai os valores não são retornados.

Comment: Então amigo, foi isso que imaginei, por isso lhe disse para colocar o return result no lugar do set. Chegou a testar assim?

Comment: Eu fiz uma modificação que resolveu o problema, mas ainda não fiquei muito satisfeito. Coloquei todos as funções em um mesmo aquivo, com exceção da importação da biblioteca de conexão e das configurações do banco, dai não precisei dar um return, usei a função res.send( retorno ) e consegui acessar os dados.

Comment: A questão é que eu queria manter as funções em arquivos separados para que a manutenção ficasse melhor. Mas ainda não consegui fazer assim, de toda forma obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Cara, você esta se esquecendo do detalhe que no Node as chamadas de entrada/saída são não-bloqueantes, pois ele executa tudo assincronamente. Ou seja, se você manda uma buscar alguma coisa no banco de dados o programa não fica parado esperando o retorno do banco, ele vai continuar executando o resto do código, e quando o banco responder os dados pro programa o Node pega eles de volta pela callback. Por isso falei desde o início falei para utilizar `return result`. Mas se você quiser insistir em fazer o programa esperar pelo retorno do banco procure como executar uma função sincrona no node.

Comment: Apesar do Node te dar essa opção de executar a função síncrona eu não te recomendo fazer isso, pois vai acabar perdendo toda a vantagem e diferencial do Node,se vai partir por essa solução procure outra linguagem que foi desenvolvida já pra trabalhar assim, como php ou java. Sugiro que leia este [artigo](https://www.opus-software.com.br/node-js/) para ter uma ideia melhor de como o Node funciona e porque.

Comment: Entendi Murilo, como disse no inicio ainda sou iniciante com Node js e não sabia desse fato da tecnologia ser não-bloqueante mas com sua sugestão de return consegui recuperar os dados. Só preciso conseguir separar mais logicamente o código agora mais por questão de legibilidade, facilidade de manutenção e reuso. Vlw pelas dicas.